# passing values from javascript to vb6 application

Tags: javascript, vb6

.Hi guys! is it possible to pass values from a javascript function to a vb6 window app that will be opened also using the said javascript function? if possible, can anyone guide me how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How will you open the VB6 window app with JavaScript? Or is that also a question? If you want to do this from JavaScript in an HTML page, then there is no way around it. If you are using JavaScript with Windows Scripting Host, this is possible.

Comment: This is possible refer to my answer on this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160827/is-there-a-way-to-send-messages-from-c-net-assemblyactivex-to-vb6-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160827/is-there-a-way-to-send-messages-from-c-net-assemblyactivex-to-vb6-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript runs in your browser which is isolated from your System. You can not simply pass values from your browser to another application.

What you can do is create a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).

Comment: .can you please give me an overview on how REST API will be useful for me?

Comment: You create a simple http server and send ajax requests from your webpage to your program.